# Restricting user-level API access in WooCommerce

Tags: php, woocommerce

I have a fulfillment partner that's integrating with my WooCommerce site via API, and I'm looking to further secure my site by restricting what that API token grants access to beyond the standard read/write scopes natively supported. As a first pass, I was able to tap into the `woocommerce_rest_check_permissions` filter and check which user the token authenticates and what post types I want to let them access:

```
$restricted_user = 2;
$allowed_types = array('shop_order');

function filter_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions( $permission, $context, $object_id, $post_type ) {
  $current_user = wp_get_current_user();
  if ($current_user->ID == $restricted_user && !in_array($post_type, $allowed_types)) {
    return false;
  }
  return $permission;
};
add_filter( 'woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 'filter_woocommerce_rest_check_permissions', 10, 4 );
```

While this is a step in the right direction, it's not granular enough. Ideally I want to ensure that tokens from the fulfillment partner's user can only retrieve orders that contain products they fulfill, and even better would be to remove any non-relevant line items from those orders. I haven't found an action/filter that would let me tap into the response at this level, but I'm still looking.